# Travel listings module for Drupal

Tags: 7, theming

I'm using Drupal 7 and can't find a suitable module to add travel listings content type. It would be great if that module would just work by having specific fields, like location and address, as well as enable the possibility to have a main index page that lists all the listings in a category.

I found Listings module, but that's only for Drupal 6.

Thank you!

Comment: You should be able to do this by just adding your own content type of "Travel", then managing the fields on that content type and adding the fields that you need. A main index page that lists all the listings of a given category would simply just be a view.

Comment: @Jance thank you, is the "View" also a content type?

Comment: No, views is basically a gui that you can use to query for nodes in drupal. It's a module that you can add to your drupal site (https://www.drupal.org/project/views).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we have the flexibility of the content type and field creation systems you don't really need someone else to post a module creating the exact content type you need (it is unlikely your requirements are exactly the same as the author of such a module).

So instead you can yourself:

1. [Create your own custom content type](https://www.drupal.org/node/774728)
2. [Add the fields you require to the content type](https://www.drupal.org/node/774742)
3. Create a listing of your content using the [views module](http://drupal.org/project/views) - If you install the [advanced help module](https://www.drupal.org/project/advanced_help) you will get lots of help documentation on creating views by clicking the little question mark links scattered around the views user interface.

Comment: Fully agree ... Though I'd also add the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module and the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens: would you add those in relation to one of the requirements in the question or just as useful add-ons?

Comment: I'd add them to your answer, as add-ons ...